# How to access commands which was set in path variable linux terminal?

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed ubuntu subsystem for my windows 10 pc and before I installed the ubuntu subsystem, I edited my path variable on windows 10 and added to it some apps like vs code and notepad++ so I could access them with their commands on windows terminal for vscode only typing code and for notepad++ typing notepad++.

but when I want to access them in ubuntu terminal these commands (code, notepad++) don't work and I checked PATH variable in the ubuntu terminal and vscode and notepad++ were already there like in windows 10 PATH variable but those commands don't work.

Is there a way to fix this problem so I can access those apps with typing their commands in ubuntu terminal?

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  When asking a question, it's good to *be specific*.  For instance, rather than saying "those commands don't work", you should include the exact commands you typed along with the output you received.  I've made an attempt to answer your question below, but if it's not right, including those details in your question can help someone come up with the *right* answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer with the *most likely* cause I can think of for what you are seeing, but your question could really use some better details to help answer it correctly *without* guessing.  See my comment under your question for more information.

For Windows executables in the path, you need to type the *full* name, including the extension (e.g. `notepad++.exe`).  There are multiple reasons for this:

- Linux itself does not have the concept of "file extensions"
- The WSL team made the decision to force the full filename to be used when launching Windows executables so that:

  - It avoids confusion - The user always is clear that they want to launch a Windows executable
  - It avoids conflicts between Linux executables (which do not have an extension) with the same base name as their Windows counterparts.  Eg. Linux's `java` and Windows `java.exe` if both are installed.

So my *guess* from your question is that, if your path *is* correct, then you may be trying `notepad++`, but it really needs to be `notepad++.exe`.

Second, though, Visual Studio Code *does* include a Linux shell script named `code` (without an extension) that lives in the `bin` directory of the VSCode installation.  Make sure you add the `bin` directory, not the main install folder, to your Windows path.  VSCode should have asked you if you want it to set the path for you during installation.